When app is in background, and then other appsareused, switching back to our app fails to display the inappwebivewwebview
Expected behavior: When the app goes in background to use other apps, when going back to foreground, it should display the webview as it was
Current behavior: If I put app background and foreground without other extra action, it works well. If i open others apps and switch back to that app (that is then resumed to foreground), the webview isn't visible anymore/disappeared. It's only a UI issue, because i see in the logs that it keeps getting actions from the user : i can click on buttons etc. I tried everything and the only way i found the to bring back the webview visible are
close app and reopen
